# How do I change my StreetPass message

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, streetpass, streetpass-mii-plaza

When I meet new people in streetpass, my Mii says something that I'd like to change. I can't find the setting for it. Where do I change it?

Comment: It sounds like you're talking about the game **StreetPass Mii Plaza**, not StreetPass in general. I've added the tag. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. While in the main menu/plaza, select *your* Mii and press A.
2. Choose **Mii Settings**.
3. Choose **Edit Greeting**.
4. You will get the option to enter a new message and facial expression.

You may also wish to review the **Edit Profile** option in Mii Settings. When others meet your Mii, they may be told one of the facts in this section in addition to your greeting.